# Record audio using Google Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

We are looking to build Google Action where it will record small snippets (like a voice TODO list) and can be played later.

Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - no. Google does not provide access to the audio stream from the Assistant. You can get the Speech To Text (STT) processed by Google, however, using the [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) API.

Comment: That would provide in the text form and user can never listen to what he/she recorded.

Comment: That is correct. As I said - Google does not provide access to the audio stream from the Assistant.

Comment: it stores everything here: https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=31
but still it is just text