# Is it possible to record audio and play it afterwards on Google Assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I'd like to know if it's possible to record an audio extract on Google Assistant (with Dialogflow and Firebase) and play it later? The idea is to:

1. Ask the user to tell his name vocally.
2. Record it.
3. Play it afterwards.

I read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104621/record-audio-using-google-actions). The answer was no, but maybe there's an update as now we can listen to what we said on Google Assistant "myactivity" as seen [here](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/07/5/1550243250-google-assistant-sound-recorded.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still no, as a developer. While users have recordings available, there's no way to access them programmatically and no way to play them through Dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this great article](https://medium.com/google-developers/make-audio-recordings-with-actions-on-google-3094158c2a2d?fbclid=IwAR2auwxQaBiRF-G7thOM2viAwP8aKbdgLq7_MeOS9OlVZej19dKs9BAebKs) which explains a trick to record audio and play it back on the Google Assistant using a progressive web app.

The design consists of thses two parts:

  A web client for recording and uploading the audio files to Google Cloud Storage.

  An Action that plays the audio file from Cloud Storage

You'll also find the url of the open-sourced code on github at the end of the article.